# How to reverse % operation in python

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, modulo

For example:

```
x = (y*6) % 26 #this is  a consistent formula
18 = (y*6) % 26
```

How would I solve for y? Or is there a way to reverse a % operation easily?

Comment: There isn't an easy way. There are multiple solutions for `y`.

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modular_inverse#Python If it helps.

Comment: How would I solve for y? I'm unaware how to handle variable movement when a % is involved

Comment: There's infinite amount of solutions: `ys = (3 + 13 * k for k in itertools.count(0))`

Comment: This question belongs to [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Yes, you can easily reverse `x = y % m` **if** you also store `z = y // m`, in which case `y = (z * m) + x`. (Or, trivially, `y` itself, in which case `y`.) Otherwise, as has been amply demonstrated below, no.

Comment: The canonical general solution will provide results in Z(13) (i.e. modulo 13).  It will be of the form `y=(x+26*(x%3))/6`.  As others have mentioned, there are an infinite number of integer solutions.

Comment: While this question might also be a good fit for Math.SE, it is **also** on topic for SO.

Answer (score 5):

You can't really reverse modulo arithmetic like that. Modulo arithmetic returns basically equivalence groups. Think about a calendar...

Calendars ( and clocks ) are mod 12.

3 months after October is January, ie (10 + 3) % 12 == 1
15 months after October is January. ie (10 + 15) % 12 == 1 
etc...

so your question seems to ask if you can tell what year it is by knowing what calendar month it is, and this is of course impossible

Comment: This is a perfect analogy! Love it!

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact way to reverse the operation as you have lost information as % only gives you the remainder when two numbers are divided.

It is like saying that if I divide x by 6 I get a whole number and a remainder of 3. I cant say what X is - it could be 9, it could be 15 or any of an infinite number of possibilities. To work it out you need the whole number as well as the modulus.

Why are you trying to do this - perhaps we can help if you tells us more of the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

18 = (y*6) % 26

means that

y*6=n*26+18 where n can be *any integer value*. So

y=n* 26/6 + 3

or

y=n* 13/3 + 3

You may now say that y is an integer, too.  This only happens for

y=n* 13 + 3

so, y= 3, 16, 29, 42, ...